# Exclude Single or multiple property in a C# Class

Tags: c#, oop

Here I have class "test".

```
public class test
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public int c { get; set; }
    public int d { get; set; }
}

void call1(test obj )
{

// Question: I need to exclude the property a. which means "test.a" should not able to access or view. 


}

void call2(test obj )
 {
// I need to exclude the property both a & b         

        return;
 }
```

Comment: Where is call1 and call2 methods located? I mean are they in the same class as test or are they in some other class or are they present in 2 seperate classes. Also are those classes within the same assembly?

Comment: Why don't you use interfaces? You can expose any properties via appropriate interface.

Comment: @Ganesan: You may want to read the MSDN reference (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) about access modifiers.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. The above scenario are implementing in restful wcf call. For example, While inserting into DB they can able to view/send all the fields except primary column. But in update, some of the columns are not updatable. That's the reason i am hiding the property for those methods.  In method one (call1), i would hide only property a. In method two (call2), i would hide both property a & b.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *interfaces* here:

```
public interface IRestrictedNoAandB {
  int c { get; set; }
  int d { get; set; }
} 

public interface IRestrictedNoA: IRestrictedNoAandB {
  int b { get; set; }
} 

public class test: IRestrictedNoA {
  public int a { get; set; }
  public int b { get; set; }
  public int c { get; set; }
  public int d { get; set; }
}

// You can't access property "a" within "call1" method
void call1(IRestrictedNoA obj ) {...}
// You can't access properties "a" and "b" within "call2" method
void call2(IRestrictedNoAandB obj ) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually i am looking only one class. Dynamically this should be hidden. i read some articles. now i can't remember. In function definition we can able exclude the properties in parameter section. void call1 (test obj { excludeproperty a  }) {  }. I gone through like this only.

Answer (score 0):

you cant do this in OOP. once a property is public it will be accessible to everybody. What instead you can do is create to models like

```
public class test1
{
    //public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public int c { get; set; }
    public int d { get; set; }
}

public class test2
{
    //public int a { get; set; }
    //public int b { get; set; }
    public int c { get; set; }
    public int d { get; set; }
}
```

and use these in the two methods mentioned. Then use an object mapper like `Glue` or `ObjectMapper` to automatially map from test to test1 and test2

but using this you might have to change the structure of your program a little bit and it would be awsm if you return test1 and test2 instead of void and then change the values of the main test instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually i am looking only one class. Dynamically should be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with two methods and new, you return an anonymous object which is a "partial" view of test.

```
public class test
{
    private int a { get; set; }
    private int b { get; set; }
    private int c { get; set; }
    private int d { get; set; }

    public object testWithoutA()
    {
        var test = new
        {
            this.b,
            this.c,
            this.d
        };
        return test;
    }

    public object testWithoutAAndB()
    {
        var test = new
        {
            this.c,
            this.d
        };
        return test;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE: The question concerns incoming data from WCF REST PUT**

Assuming that you are working with stored procedures, why not create 2 stored procedures which ignore in one case 'a' and 'a' and 'b'?

Comment: And how will he be able to access the properties inside call1 and call2 methods? Please add call1 and call2 method signatures and the way it will be able to access the properties so that OP is able to understand better.

Comment: I need to know the scope of call1 and call2?

Comment: Sure. Thanks for your quick reply. The above scenario are implementing in restful wcf call. For example, While inserting into DB they can able to view/send all the fields except primary column while calling the REST. But in update, some of the columns are not updatable. That's the reason i am hiding the property for those methods. In method one (call1), i would hide only property a. In method two (call2), i would hide both property a & b.

Comment: What do you use as data layer, Entity Framework? SQL SP?

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the structure of an object in run time.

but there are plenty of ways to prevent accessing a property of an instance, for example see this codes:

```
public class Test
{

    // define some private varibales:
    private int _a;
    private int _b;
    private bool accessA = true;
    private bool accessB = true;

    public int a
    {
        get
        {
            if (accessA)
            {
                return _a;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("At this moment this property was excluded.");
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if (accessA)
            {
                _a = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("At this moment this property was excluded.");
            }
        }
    }
    public int b
    {
        get
        {
            if (accessB)
            {
                return _b;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("At this moment this property was excluded.");
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if (accessB)
            {
                _b = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("At this moment this property was excluded.");
            }
        }
    }
    public int c { get; set; }
    public int d { get; set; }

    public void ExcludeA()
    {
        accessA = false;
    }

    public void ExcludeB()
    {
        accessB = false;
    }
}

    public void call1(Test obj)
    {
        //do some work here ....

        obj.ExcludeA();
    }

    public void call2(Test obj)
    {
        // do some work here ...

        obj.ExcludeA();
        obj.ExcludeB();
    }
```